# Wysiwyg Edit image by double clicking

Tags: media, wysiwyg

Right now, to modify an image, I need to select the image and click on the image icon in the toolbar.

Is there a way in [WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/WYSIWYG) to double click on an image and open automatically the image manager?